# Emulating Program's Initial Run (ie no NSUserDefaults file)

Tags: swift, macos, nsuserdefaults

What is the accepted way to try to emulate a user installing my MacOS application and running it for the first time as far as user defaults go?
I tried deleting my .plist file in the ~/Library/Containers/program_name/Data/Library/Preferences directly, but that gives errors and refuses to save/read user defaults.

Is there something else I should do to emulate installing an app and running it the first time?

I just upgraded to OS 10.13, and I don't recall having this issue before. It would just create a new plist file when I wrote to it for the first time.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with User Defaults on the Mac, but assuming it's a dictionary like in iOS, Can't you just delete all the keys?

Comment: I did try deleting by doing a removePersistentDomain. That removes all the keys, but it keeps the file and the header and footer type of information in the file. It's when I move/hide/delete the file that it gives me issues.

Comment: When the user installs the app, the ~/Library/Containers/program_name folder doesn't exist. Remove (or move) this folder to emulate a first time run.

Comment: I tried removing just the Preferences folder, then the program_name folder. both did not work. I will say that I'm referring to running in Xcode, not as a stand-alone application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaults delete com.yourdomain.YourApp`.

AFAIK, the plist file is only a cache, and not intended to be the authoritative version of the defaults database.

Comment: What is the location of the defaults database? AFAIK, the defaults database is a cache and the defaults are stored in the plist file on disk.

Comment: This command should be run from terminal. I think the cache is stored in memory as restarting clears it.